# Msgbox box does not appear on selection change and does not go away with ok button click

Tags: excel, vba

The msgbox does not appear until after I've click the target address made a change then go to another cell make a change then go back to the target address before the box appears.

I've tried to make a custom dialog box so that it would appear over the target cell but could not get it to work. The same thing happens in the rest of my code with the DTPicker1. Once the target range address is selected, the formatting changes don't happen until I've moved to the next cell made changes then go back and click on the cells again. Not sure what to try to fix this code attached:

```
Private Sub DTPicker1_CallbackKeyDown(ByVal KeyCode as Integer, ByVal Shift 
   as Integer, ByVal Callbackfield as String, ByVal CallbackDate as Date)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Selectionchange(ByVal Target as Range)
    If not Intersect(Target, Range("a3")) is nothing then
        Msgbox (“To change the date/time, Select the number and use the arrows.”)
    End if 
    With Sheet1.DTPicker1
        .Height = 20
        .Width = 125
        .Format = dtpCustom
        .CustomFormat = "ddHHmmZMMMyy"
    If Not intersect(Target, Range("a3:a502")) is nothing then
        .Visible = True
        .Top = Target.Top
        .Left = Target.offset(0,1).left
        .Linkedcell = Target.address
        Me.Range(DTPicker1.LinkedCell)= Format(DTPicker1.value,Me.Range("a3").NumberFormat)
    Else
        .Visible = False
    End If 
    End With
    If not intersect(Target, Range("b3:b502")) is nothing then 
        Randomize
        Target.value=StaticRand()
    End if
    If not intersect(Target, Range("c3:c502")) is nothing then
        Randomize
        Target.Value = Int((6-1+1)* StaticRand+1)
            If Range("b3").value < 0.25 then
            Target.value =target.value & "NO COVERAGE"
    End if
    End if
```

The expected results would be to click the cell, have the DTPicker1 enabled then click the cell to enter the changes in the correct format. The cell only changes after coming back from executing another cell then returning to the original.

Comment: What's going on with `If not Intersect(Target, Range(‘a3”)) is nothing then`? You seem to have an apostrophe there instead of a quotation mark.

Comment: The curly quotes are also not ASCII 34, so ...that code can't compile as-is copy/pasted into the VBE

Comment: Also `… , ByVal Call backfield as String, …` is no valid syntax! Remove the `Call`.

Comment: All, those were typos in transposing the code to Stackoverflow. The code is correct in my excel minus the typos here. I corrected those but none of your answers are to my question they just address my typos.

Comment: I fixed the curly qoutes from copy/paste. Does anyone have an idea why it is not working?